# Can't find any designing options in System->Configuration->General->Design

Tags: magento

i have just installed magento c,e 2.1 and trying to make changes in the design but when i got to System->Configuration->General->Design the only thing that shows is Search Engine Robot and a drop down for default robots. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: problem solved! .. found the change theme and rest designing options in Content->Configuration->Design :)

Comment: you can answer your own question

Answer (score 0):

problem solved! I found the change theme and rest designing options in Content->Configuration->Design :)